# Run Eclipse Plug-in Test with included workspace projects

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm writing a small Eclipse plug-in and some tests for it. I'm starting the plug-in tests by specifying them to run in `Headless Mode`. I want to access the active Java projects within the workspace in those tests, but when I execute them, the workspace is empty. I use the following code to get all Java projects (which works fine):

```
IWorkspaceRoot myWorkspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
for(IProject project : myWorkspaceRoot.getProjects()) {
        if(project.isOpen() && isJavaProject(project)) {
                IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
                projects.put(project.getName(), javaProject);
        }
}
```

However, the projects are always empty. This is due to the fact that the `Headless Mode` starts a new Eclipse instance with an empty workspace I guess. My question is: can I somehow either specify that the tests should run in the current Eclipse instance OR can I specify the projects I want to have in the newly created workspace?

Comment: You can't do either of those things. You need to set up projects in the test workspace.

Comment: Can you provide any link or sample code for that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out an easy way to setup a test `workspace` and wanted to share it with you (even though this means answering my own question):

1. Open `Eclipse` and create a new `workspace` somewhere on the disc
2. Add some sample projects to the new `workspace`
3. Open an `Eclipse` instance which holds the `Plug-in Test` code
4. In the `JUnit Plug-in Test Launch Configuration`, go to the `Main` tab

[image: Launch configuration for a JUnit Plug-in Test]

5. Specify the `workspace` created in *1)* and populated in *2)*
6. Run the test, which will start with the specified `workspace` and all projects in it