# Setup Eclipse Workspace in Java Code

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

I am writing a `JUnit Plug-In Test`, which will open a `Java Project` from the `WorkSpace` and pass it to a third party library for further processing. This is what I have so far:

```
@Test
public void testJavaProjectForwarding() {
    try {
        IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
        IWorkspace workspace = root.getWorkspace();
        Map<String, IJavaProject> javaProjects = new HashMap<>();

        System.out.println("Nr. of projects: " + javaProjects.size());

        for(IProject project : workspace.getProjects()) {
            if(project.isOpen() && isJavaProject(project)) {
                IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
                javaProjects.put(project.getName(), javaProject);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Nr. of Java projects: " + javaProjects.size());
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I print out first the number of overall projects and second the number of `Java` projects. Both outputs are, however, 0. This is due to the empty workspace when running a `Plug-in Test`. My question is: how can I setup the `Plug-in Test` workspace to include projects? Do I have to do it in the `Launch Configuration` or can I add them programmatically in the test somewhere? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can create projects programmatically but this is quite a lot of code. You could just open Eclipse specifying the 'Plug-in Test' workspace and create them with Eclipse.

Comment: As Greg says, creating the project manually in Eclipse is a good option. You can even zip the project up and have your test extract it and open it. If you do want to create it programmatically then the `JavaProjectWizard` class has the code you need.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks a lot for your help! Could you give me a short link where I can find more details or give a small list of instructions on how to do so? Thanks again!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Eclipse Plug-in Test with included workspace projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088926/run-eclipse-plug-in-test-with-included-workspace-projects)

Comment: Not a duplicate, mutable environment for unit tests should not be prepared by hand.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a project handle with
  org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot.getProject(String) (returns
  IProject)
- Load prepared project description:
  org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace.loadProjectDescription(IPath)
  (returns IProjectDescription, takes a path to .project file as argument)
- Actually create a project reference in workspace:
  org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject.create(IProjectDescription,
  IProgressMonitor)
- Open the project: org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject.open(int,
  IProgressMonitor)

<sub>Example: org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.WizardProjectsImportPage.createExistingProject(ProjectRecord, IProgressMonitor). It shows how to copy source project, so that unit tests don't change it. Instead of using precreated (with Eclipse, for example) project description you can create one from scratch.</sub>